# Parsing string in rust

Tags: parsing, rust

I want to parse the string
`"{\"hello , world\",quote,\"\\\",\\\"q\"}"`into `vec!["hello , world", "quote", "\",\"q"]`
I have tried to for loop and check `"` then split `,` but it has many corner cases that I couldn't solve, such as `\"` in the quote.

Comment: Please provide the code you've tried.

Comment: what i'd do is to replace {} with []  and parse using serde_json

Comment: this example is a bit unfortunate, because it uses `,` as delimiter, but also is used and not escaped in strings, so you can't easily split it. do you get this string from somewhere or you are creating it in other part of your program?

Comment: This example seems a little inconsistent, once \"hello, world\" is converted into one string "hello, world", but next to it *quote* without any escaped quotes and it's also "quote". Are you creating this string yourself somewhere else?

Comment: I received it from supabase-realtime from webSocket. The schema of it is array of texts.

Comment: I have tried, let code = "[".to_string() + code.trim_end_matches("}").trim_start_matches("{") + "]"; let tmp = serde_json::from_str::<Value>(&code).unwrap(); but I found an error after unwrap.

Answer (score 1):

I got it! Just for loop and check the tokens. Then, use `serde_json` to parse the data.

```rust
fn parse_code(code: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    let code = code.trim_end_matches("}").trim_start_matches("{");
    let mut ans = Vec::new();
    let mut start_string = false;
    let mut extra = false;
    let mut pre = '\0';
    for ch in code.chars() {
        if ch == '"' && pre != '\\' {
            start_string = !start_string;
        }
        if pre == ',' && start_string == false {
            start_string = true;
            extra = true;
            ans.push('"');
        }
        if ch == ',' && start_string == true && extra == true {
            start_string = false;
            extra = false;
            ans.push('"');
        }
        ans.push(ch);
        pre = ch;
    }
    if extra {
        ans.push('"');
    }
    let ans: String = ans.iter().collect();
    let code = "[".to_string() + &ans + "]";
    serde_json::from_str::<Value>(&code)
        .unwrap()
        .as_array()
        .unwrap()
        .iter()
        .map(|x| x.as_str().unwrap().to_string())
        .collect()
}
```